# Enum to return an instance of an interface using generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I would like to have an enum to return an instance of an interface, using generics.  I can't quite figure it out yet.  I'm not exactly sure how to phrase my question.  Below is the code that I am trying to get working.  It won't compile because the enum wants the constructor to handle ImplementingClass explicity.

My interface

```
public interface MyInterface {

}
```

My implementing class

```
public class ImplementingClass implements MyInterface {

}
```

The enum I'm trying to get working

```
public enum MyEnum {

    CASE1(“CODE1”, ImplementingClass.class);

    private String code;
    private Class<MyInterface> aClass;

    private MyEnum(String code, Class<MyInterface> aClass) {
        this.code = code;
        this.aClass = aClass;
    }    

    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    public MyInterface getInstance() {
        return this.aClass.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using enums correctly... this code won't work unless you make MyEnum a class

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a `Class<MyInterface>` can only be `MyInterface.class`, and not any implementing class such as `ImplementingClass.class`.

You can use a wildcard to create an upper bound on the declaration of `aClass` to take a `Class` object representing any class that implements `MyInterface`:

```
private Class<? extends MyInterface> aClass;

private MyEnum(String code, Class<? extends MyInterface> aClass) {
    this.code = code;
    this.aClass = aClass;
}
```

Comment: OK, thank you.  Is there any way to instantiate that class without throwing the InstantiationException and IllegalAccessExceptions?  Or a better way overall to solve this?

Comment: No, if you have a `Class` object, and you want an instance of that class, then there is no way around having to catch those exceptions or to having to declare them with a `throws` clause on the method.

Answer (score 0):

Some use of wildcards and casting do the magic:

```
public enum MyEnum {

 CASE1("CODE1", (Class<? extends MyInterface>)ImplementingClass.class);

 private String code;
 private Class<? extends MyInterface> aClass;

 private MyEnum(String code, Class<? extends MyInterface> aClass) {
    this.code = code;
    this.aClass = aClass;
 }    

 //...
}
```